# Product Images in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images

Is it possible to not have the images popping out of their frame and filling the whole page when I click on them? I would like nothing at all to happen when you click on the image in the product page.

Comment: The quick way is to do it by  CSS. Add `pointer-events:none` to `fotorama__stage` class.

Comment: Can I add this to my theme?

Comment: Yes, you can add a new class in your custom theme's css. like `.fotorama__stage { pointer-events:none }`

Comment: Can you please type your comment as an answer Prince? So I can accept it? I think that would be useful for me and for the community.

Comment: Yes, it's very useful for other developers.

Comment: Definitely, for future ones!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method - 1** - Override `view.xml` from `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml`

To `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/etc/view.xml`

Now change

```
<var name="allowfullscreen">true</var>
```

To

```
<var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
```

Now flush the cache and try.

**Method - 2:** The simple and quick way to disable opening default popup on product page by adding `pointer-events: none` in css of `fotorama__stage` class

Open css of custom theme and add new class `fotorama__stage`

```
.catalog-product-view .fotorama__stage 
{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: When I did this the images acted in the way you said they would but the spacing between the rows of products got messed up. The first row overlaps the second. Any ideas?

Comment: Also the css file disappeared when I cleared static files.... Im in developer mode.